# Strip text properties in savehist

Tags: text-properties, saving

I save the `kill-ring` using the `savehist` package. `savehist` saves the kill ring with text-properties intact.

Unfortunately, this is a problem.

I have a rather large emacs config, and I use a lot of highlighting. Here is the first element of my `kill-ring`

```
#("avehist-printable value)\n         (prin1 `(setq ,symbol ',value) (current-buffer))\n          (insert ?\\n))))))\n    ;; If autosaving, avoid writing if nothing has changed since the\n    ;; last write." 0 23   (fontified t wrap-prefix     #("     " 0 5        (fontified t)))   23 24   (fontified t face     (rainbow-delimiters-depth-8-face)     wrap-prefix     #("      " 0 5        (fontified t)))   24 25   (fontified t wrap-prefix     #("     " 0 5        (fontified t)))   25 32   (fontified t wrap-prefix     #("       " 0 7        (fontified t)))   32 33   (fontified t face     (rainbow-delimiters-depth-8-face)     wrap-prefix     #("          " 0 7        (fontified t)))   33 40   (fontified t wrap-prefix     #("         " 0 7        (fontified t)))   40 41   (fontified t face     (rainbow-delimiters-depth-9-face)     wrap-prefix     #("          " 0 7        (fontified t)))   41 61   (fontified t wrap-prefix     #("         " 0 7        (fontified t)))   61 62   (fontified t face     (rainbow-delimiters-depth-9-face)     wrap-prefix     #("          " 0 7        (fontified t)))   62 63   (fontified t wrap-prefix     #("         " 0 7        (fontified t)))   63 64   (fontified t face     (rainbow-delimiters-depth-9-face)     wrap-prefix     #("          " 0 7        (fontified t)))   64 78   (fontified t wrap-prefix     #("         " 0 7        (fontified t)))   78 79   (fontified t face     (rainbow-delimiters-depth-9-face)     wrap-prefix     #("          " 0 7        (fontified t)))   79 80   (fontified t face     (rainbow-delimiters-depth-8-face)     wrap-prefix     #("          " 0 7        (fontified t)))   80 81   (fontified t wrap-prefix     #("         " 0 7        (fontified t)))   81 88   (fontified t wrap-prefix     #("         " 0 7        (fontified t)))   88 89   (fontified t face     (rainbow-delimiters-depth-8-face)     wrap-prefix     #("          " 0 7        (fontified t)))   89 99   (fontified t wrap-prefix     #("         " 0 7        (fontified t)))   99 100   (fontified t face     (rainbow-delimiters-depth-8-face)     wrap-prefix     #("         " 0 7        (fontified t)))   100 101   (fontified t face     (rainbow-delimiters-depth-7-face)     wrap-prefix     #("        " 0 7        (fontified t)))   101 102   (fontified t face     (rainbow-delimiters-depth-6-face)     wrap-prefix     #("        " 0 7        (fontified t)))   102 103   (fontified t face     (rainbow-delimiters-depth-5-face)     wrap-prefix     #("        " 0 7        (fontified t)))   103 104   (fontified t face     (rainbow-delimiters-depth-4-face)     wrap-prefix     #("        " 0 7        (fontified t)))   104 105   (fontified t face     (rainbow-delimiters-depth-3-face)     wrap-prefix     #("        " 0 7        (fontified t)))   105 106   (fontified t wrap-prefix     #("       " 0 7        (fontified t)))   106 110   (fontified t wrap-prefix     #("    ;; " 0 4        (fontified t)        4 7        (fontified t face font-lock-comment-delimiter-face)))   110 113   (fontified t face font-lock-comment-delimiter-face wrap-prefix     #("    ;; " 0 4        (fontified t)        4 7        (fontified t face font-lock-comment-delimiter-face)))   113 175   (fontified t face font-lock-comment-face wrap-prefix     #("    ;; " 0 4        (fontified t)        4 7        (fontified t face font-lock-comment-delimiter-face)))   175 179   (fontified t wrap-prefix     #("    ;; " 0 4        (fontified t)        4 7        (fontified t face font-lock-comment-delimiter-face)))   179 182   (fontified t face font-lock-comment-delimiter-face wrap-prefix     #("    ;; " 0 4        (fontified t)        4 7        (fontified t face font-lock-comment-delimiter-face)))   182 193   (fontified t face font-lock-comment-face wrap-prefix     #("    ;; " 0 4        (fontified t)        4 7        (fontified t face font-lock-comment-delimiter-face))))
```

In essence, text properties bloat my `~/.emacs.d/savehist` by almost a factor of 100. I'm looking at ~30MB of kill ring. This is bad for all sorts of reasons. Not least because it makes emacs very slow.

How can I tell `savehist` to strip text properties from the `kill-ring` before saving, without deleting the properties for the current session?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the following to your init-file:

```el
(defun unpropertize-kill-ring ()
  (setq kill-ring (mapcar 'substring-no-properties kill-ring)))

(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'unpropertize-kill-ring)
```

#### How it works

`substring-no-properties` removes any text properties from a given string. `kill-ring` is a list of strings; we're using `mapcar` to apply `substring-no-properties` to each string that is currently in the kill ring. The result of the `mapcar` call (i.e., a list of strings without any text properties) is used to override the original value of `kill-ring`.

`savehist-mode` saves the minibuffer history and any additional variables in `savehist-additional-variables` when you quit Emacs. So in the last line we simply tell Emacs to "unpropertize" the kill ring on quit. Note that this happens before `savehist` does its thing because `add-hook` *prepends* functions by default, so `unpropertize-kill-ring` will be called before `savehist-autosave` (which is the actual function that gets executed when you quit Emacs).

Comment: Are you aware of `savehist-save-hook`?

Comment: @PythonNut Yes I am. If you never call `savehist-save` manually, you can add the function for "unpropertizing" strings to `savehist-save-hook` instead of `kill-emacs-hook`. But if you want to preserve the option of calling `savehist-save` during an editing session without losing text properties of recent kill ring entries, `kill-emacs-hook` is a better choice.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to make sure that _wasn't_ a solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. :)

Answer (score 6):

One simple solution is to use [`savehist-20.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/savehist-20%2b.el).

It is a version of `savehist.el` that works with all Emacs versions (20+). It automatically strips history elements of properties, and it does not save variables in `savehist-additional-variables` whose values are propertized strings.

In other words, you can read the file it saves even in an Emacs version (e.g. 20) that barfs on propertized strings.

Comment: Basically all of the elements of `kill-ring` are propertied, so it sounds like this would trow away the `kill-ring` wholesale.

Comment: Yes.  (If you don't want that then you can tweak one line of the code.)