# High CPU/memory usage and abnormally large savehist file?

Tags: spacemacs, history, history-variables, savehist-mode

I'm starting to use [Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs) and occasionally I get stuck with Emacs beginning to require infinite amount of CPU and memory. Inspecting my `.emacs.d/.cache` folder reveals that the file `savehist` is 1.16 GB large... Deleting this file made Emacs work again.

Googling returned no result for me. Is there any precedent of such an abnormality, and how might one try to debug and fix it.

Comment: Did you inspect the specific contents of the file? That might have given you a clue of the nature of your problem.

Comment: Seems to be the same issue mentioned here: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/9409 relating to high cpu/memory for the `savehist-autosave `.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would guess that's a result of one specific persistent variable getting enormous (it just seems less likely that you would have multiple instances at the same time), but if you've deleted the file you can't see which variable it was.

You can always rename the file rather than deleting it, so that you can make Emacs happy again, but still analyse the data.

If you recreate this situation, and the file is really massive, opening it in Emacs to check might not be a great idea. I would use `grep` to find out the offset for each variable, and just look for any really big jumps:

```
$ grep -E -b -o '^\(setq [^ ]+' ~/.emacs.d/.cache/savehist
```

(Or whatever your `savehist-file` path is -- the standard filename is `~/.emacs.d/history` but I presume `~/.emacs.d/.cache/savehist` is what Spacemacs configures.)

---

*Edit: The results of this from the comments below were:*

```
116:(setq savehist-minibuffer-history-variables 
350:(setq regexp-search-ring 
566:(setq magit-read-rev-history 
637:(setq read-expression-history 
694:(setq command-history 
19045:(setq helm-grep-history 
20687:(setq minibuffer-history 
75425:(setq file-name-history 
83278:(setq ido-file-history 
83377:(setq evil-ex-history 
111288:(setq kill-ring 
1162765006:(setq mark-ring 
1162765028:(setq search-ring 
1162765052:(setq regexp-search-ring 
1162765268:(setq extended-command-history
```

*From this we can see that `kill-ring` is the biggest culprit by some orders of magnitude!*

*Edit 2:* [Strip text properties in savehist](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/4187) almost certainly accounts for the excessive size of the `kill-ring` entry. The remainder of this answer is still useful information, but I recommend also looking at that other Q&A.

---

It's possible that you need to fix a bug somewhere -- whatever is causing that value to become so huge. Even if you're not writing a value to the history file, Emacs may still be burning a lot of memory on that data (especially if you rarely quit Emacs, and it's accumulating rapidly).

If that's not an issue, though, it might be sufficient for Emacs to simply not persist the variable(s) in question -- if they're not persistent, the size won't be growing continually from session to session.

If you just don't want it written to the history file, and the offending variable is a member of `savehist-additional-variables`, then it's probably your own config which is responsible for having added it, so you should find and remedy that.

Otherwise it's most likely a minibuffer history variable which savehist is adding automatically, in which case you could add it to `savehist-ignored-variables` to prevent this from occuring.

Alternatively (and preferably) for variables which are explicitly used as histories, you should be able to alleviate this via the `history-length` variable, which means you can still maintain the most recent history for variables of interest. Note in particular that you can specify this on a per-variable basis:

```
This variable only affects history lists that don't specify their own
maximum lengths.  Setting the `history-length' property of a history
variable overrides this default.
```

e.g.:

```el
(setq history-length 100)
(put 'minibuffer-history 'history-length 50)
(put 'evil-ex-history 'history-length 50)
(put 'kill-ring 'history-length 25)
```

*n.b. If you have set the value of `history-length` to `t`, that disables truncation, and the affected histories will be allowed to grow without restraints! (of course an integer value which is simply very very large can be just as problematic.)*

Note that setting a (sensible integer) `history-length` value is beneficial for Emacs' memory usage as well as the history file size, because the list truncation happens as history items are added, and so the in-memory variable never exceeds its maximum length + 1.

Also note that `kill-ring` is not a history variable, and so it is unaffected by `history-length`. It does however have its own analogous constraint in the `kill-ring-max` variable, so you should definitely check your setting for that.

You may like to make `kill-ring` an ignored variable regardless, unless you particularly want that to persist between sessions. (I don't think that it's persistent by default, mind, so you should maybe check why that's happening?)

Finally, you can utilise `savehist-save-hook` to run your own custom functions before the variables are written to the history file, so you can do pretty much anything you want at that point. For example if you wished to maintain a larger `history-length` while Emacs is running, but only write a smaller sub-set of that data to the history file when Emacs exits, then you could write a custom function to cut those lists down to size.

Comment: Thank you. Running `grep` was efficient. The following is the result: ```116:(setq savehist-minibuffer-history-variables
350:(setq regexp-search-ring
566:(setq magit-read-rev-history
637:(setq read-expression-history
694:(setq command-history
19045:(setq helm-grep-history
20687:(setq minibuffer-history
75425:(setq file-name-history
83278:(setq ido-file-history
83377:(setq evil-ex-history
111288:(setq kill-ring
1162765006:(setq mark-ring
1162765028:(setq search-ring
1162765052:(setq regexp-search-ring
1162765268:(setq extended-command-history```

Comment: Could be something to do with `evil`? I guess I'll disable those problematic variables now.

Comment: `.cache` folder does not exist? is it created in some other directory?

Comment: alper: that's a non-standard path, and I've commented on that fact in the answer already.

Comment: If `grep` only reports "binary file matches" without displaying the desired output and offsets, you can add the `-a` or `--text` option to the command to force grep to treat the file as text.

Answer (score 1):

[Phils' answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12116/14965) is great and put me on the right track to solve my similar issue.

However, I found that directly locating long lines in the history file gave more specific results.

```bash
cat $your_hist_file_backup | \
    awk '(length($0) > 1000) {printf (" - Line %d is %d characters long\n", NR, length($0) );}'
```

and then identify preceding `setq` line. I'm using `cut` to truncate long lines.

```bash
cat $your_hist_file_backup | \
    sed -n -e '/^(setq/ p' -e "${your_culprit_line_num}q" | \
    cut -c 1-80
```

In my case, it definitely established that `kill-ring` was to blame.

Check `spacemacs-defaults/init-savehist()` in `file:layers/+spacemacs/spacemacs-defaults/packages.el`