# How do I disable savehist-autosave in emacs?

Tags: auto-save, savehist-mode

Because my emacs editor has become completely unreliable / unusable due to the frequent freezes - I'd like to disable this. But I can't figure out how?

The actual issue is described by myself and others here: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/9409

When I tried searching for this online:

This page offers no solution: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Disabling-auto_002dsave_002dmode.html

It only directs you to https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save.html#Auto-Save which also has no solution

Comment: Is your problem an instance of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12086/abnormally-large-savehist-file ?

Comment: Thank you so much @phils that has fixed the unstableness issue - and has made emacs incredibly more responsive.

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad that did the trick.

Comment: I would suggest accepting @lawlist's answer, as it does cover the original question of how to disable `savehist-mode`, even if you didn't end up needing to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable `savehist-mode`, which is a *global* minor-mode, one can use: `(savehist-mode -1)`  When disabling `savehist-mode`, the function `savehist-uninstall` is called ... `savehist-minibuffer-hook` is removed from the `minibuffer-setup-hook`, and `savehist-autosave` is removed from the `kill-emacs-hook`, and the timer `savehist-timer` is canceled.

However, `savehist-mode` is *not* enabled in Emacs 26 by default.  Therefore, the better approach would be to find out where in the user-configuration of the original poster `savehist-mode` is being enabled and remove that line of code or comment it out.  The easiest method would be to use `grep` and search for the term `savehist-mode`.

`savehist-mode` has been around for ages and it is highly unlikely it is responsible for making Emacs freeze frequently.  Turning it off for purposes of troubleshooting, however, may be a worthwhile endeavor.

The best approach is to try and get a backtrace when Emacs freezes.  If pressing `C-g` does not suffice, then consider building Emacs from source and launching Emacs under `gdb` ... with the terminal starting directory being the `src` directory so that the `.gdbinit` gets loaded.  Then, when Emacs freezes, you can force a backtrace ... which is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: `savehist` can sometimes cause problems if the user is telling it to save some *really large* value.  The example I've seen which springs to mind is the entire kill ring with all text properties printed out in readable form.  The resulting file can be enormous, but in those situations it's probably down to a small handful of variables at most.  E.g. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12086/abnormally-large-savehist-file