# Structure-preserving copying of sequences

Tags: elisp, list

The form `(cl-copy-tree TREE t)` returns a deep-copy of a sequence `TREE`.
The [the Common Lisp Hyper Spec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cp_tre.htm) explains that `copy-tree` does not preserve circularities and sharing of substructures. I.e., even if `copy-tree` delivers a deep copy it is not structure-preserving.

Is there a structure-preserving version of `tree-copy` in the elisp library shipped with emacs or even built-in?

The following example demonstrates the structural difference between the argument and the result of `copy-tree`.

```el
(let* (ret
       (print-circle t)
       (l '((1 2) (3)))
       (c (progn 
            (setcdr (nth 1 l) (car l))
            (cl-copy-tree l))))
  (setq ret (format "l: %S\nc: %S\n" l c))
  (setcar (car l) 4)
  (setcar (car c) 4)
  (setq print-circle nil)
  (concat ret (format "Effect of the structural difference:\nl: %S\nc: %S\n" l c))
  )
```

Evaluation of this form delivers:

```
l: (#1=(1 2) (3 . #1#))
c: ((1 2) (3 1 2))
Effect of the structural difference:
l: ((4 2) (3 4 2))
c: ((4 2) (3 1 2))
```

The following code shows that a library implementation of a structure-preserving version of `copy-tree` would be possible. I needed it already [for an answer related to `undo-tree`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32194/undo-tree-history-file-without-text-properties/32230?noredirect=1#comment49766_32230).

```el
(cl-defstruct (copy-tree*
               (:constructor copy-tree*-mem (&optional stack stack-new (hash (make-hash-table)))))
  stack stack-new hash)

(defmacro copy-tree*--push (el el-new mem &optional hash)
"Put EL onto the stack and EL-NEW onto stack-new in the `copy-tree*'
structure MEM. Add a key-value pair mapping EL to EL-NEW in the hash map
of mem."
  (let ((my-el (make-symbol "my-el"))
        (my-el-new (make-symbol "my-el-new"))) ; makes sure `el' is only evaluated once
    (append `(let ((,my-el ,el)
                   (,my-el-new ,el-new))
               (push ,my-el (copy-tree*-stack ,mem))
               (push ,my-el-new (copy-tree*-stack-new ,mem)))
            (and hash
                 `((puthash ,my-el ,my-el-new (copy-tree*-hash ,mem))))
            (list my-el-new))))

(defmacro copy-tree*--pop (el el-new mem)
  `(setq ,el (pop (copy-tree*-stack ,mem))
         ,el-new (pop (copy-tree*-stack-new mem))))

(defun copy-tree*--copy-node (node mem vecp)
  "If NODE is not a `cons' just return it.
Create a new copy of NODE if NODE is a `cons' not already contained in the hash map of mem (a `copy-tree*' structure). Register NODE and its copy as key-value pair in the hash table.
If NODE is already a key of the hash map return its copy.
With non-nil VECP vectors are treated analogously to conses."
  (if (or (consp node)
      (and vecp (vectorp node)))
      (let ((existing-node (gethash node (copy-tree*-hash mem))))
    (if existing-node
        existing-node
      (copy-tree*--push node (if (consp node)
                     (cons nil nil)
                   (make-vector (length node) nil))
                mem t)))
    node))

(defun copy-tree* (tree &optional vecp)
  "Structure preserving version of `cl-copy-tree'."
  (if (or (consp tree)
      (and vecp (vectorp tree)))
      (let* ((tree-new (if (consp tree) (cons nil nil)
             (make-vector (length tree) nil)))
             (mem (copy-tree*-mem))
             next
             next-new)
        (copy-tree*--push tree tree-new mem t)
        (while (copy-tree*--pop next next-new mem)
      (cond
       ((consp next)
        (setcar next-new (copy-tree*--copy-node (car next) mem vecp))
        (setcdr next-new (copy-tree*--copy-node (cdr next) mem vecp)))
       ((and vecp (vectorp next))
        (cl-loop for i from 0 below (length next) do
             (aset next-new i (copy-tree*--copy-node (aref next i) mem vecp))))))
    tree-new)
    tree))
```

The following example is a modified version of the first example.
The only modification is that `cl-copy-tree` is replaced by `copy-tree*`.

```el
(let* (ret
       (print-circle t)
       (l '((1 2) (3)))
       (c (progn 
            (setcdr (nth 1 l) (car l))
            (copy-tree* l))))
  (setq ret (format "l: %S\nc: %S\n" l c))
  (setcar (car l) 4)
  (setcar (car c) 4)
  (setq print-circle nil)
  (concat ret (format "Effect of the structural difference:\nl: %S\nc: %S\n" l c))
  )
```

The output of this form demonstrates that `copy-tree*` produces a structure-preserving copy of its argument.

```
l: (#1=(1 2) (3 . #1#))
c: (#1=(1 2) (3 . #1#))
Effect of the structural difference:
l: ((4 2) (3 4 2))
c: ((4 2) (3 4 2))
```

Comment: There is none that I'm aware of. You might consider proposing to add such a function (`M-x report-emacs-bug`).

Comment: "I needed it already for an answer related to undo-tree." - For that particular thing, I suggest instead co-operating with undo-tree's author to get some hooks added: https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/478#issuecomment-293895602

Comment: @Drew I followed your suggestion and wrote a feature request. Best regards,

Comment: Yes, I saw it. I'm sure it will get the attention it deserves.

Comment: @npostavs `copy-tree*` above is not so special to `undo-tree`. It acts very much like `copy-tree` but is structure-preserving. It has also an maybe important advantage over `copy-tree` beside that it is structure-preserving. The copy produced by `copy-tree*` can be smaller than that one produced by `copy-tree` because `copy-tree*` reuses common substructures in the same way as the original data does. In some cases this may save algorithmic costs in spite of the fact that a single step of `copy-tree*` is more expensive.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't trying to say that `copy-tree*` is a bad idea, it was just a remark about the `undo-tree` issue.

Comment: @npostavs Ah I see. That was a misunderstanding from my side. (Maybe, it was already too late.) Thanks for the clarification. I already saw the discussion about hooks for cleaning up `buffer-undo-tree` before saving. Nevertheless, even for `undo-tree` there remains the wish to duplicate the full tree. In our special application we don't want to remove the text properties in the original tree but just in the copy that is provided for saving to file. `copy-tree` damages the structure of the tree such that it does not work anymore if one saves the copy and reads it back in as undo-history.